# Stopping an ajax request without knowing which

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow

I'm using the autocomplete component of primefaces. Now what this does is you add a few characters and it will search the names accordingly. Now the trouble I am having is the 'enter' button (on keyboard)... Because I want to make the enter functional, that even if you are searching the autocomplete you can still press it and continue to get a larger list. Now this is done with a button that goes to Webflow and redirects to another page.

Now the trouble I am having is, that if the autocomplete starts searching, it starts an Ajax request and if I click the enter during it will start another request to do the redirect. But here is the catch: The first request is still active and if it returns success before my redirect is complete it just aborts the redirect giving me the page where it began.

Now the big question: How do I stop the first request I know nothing about? Blackbox wise I don't know much about the request except that it is very annoying. I cannot pass it on via JavaScript either because the autocomplete only has a function for on start which loads before the request and on complete which loads after the request.

**Edit**: Here is the code I use in case you need it to understand:

XHTML and JavaScript:

```
<p:autoComplete  value="#{simpleSearchBean.searchString}" completeMethod="#   {simpleSearchBean.completeUser}"
var="user" itemLabel="#{user}" itemValue="#{user}" forceSelection="false"
minQueryLength="3" maxResults="10" name="search_block_form" id="edit-search-block-form-1" size="30" queryDelay="500" style="float:left;">
     <p:ajax event="itemSelect" oncomplete="autoClickSearchButton()" update="@all"/>
</p:autoComplete>

<p:commandButton action="simpleUserSearch" title="#{msgs_common['common.search']}" name="op" id="edit-submit" image="ui-icon ui-icon-search" style="float:left;"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function autoClickSearchButton(){
    jQuery('#search-block-form\\:edit-submit').click();
}

jQuery('#search-block-form\\:edit-search-block-form-1').keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        jQuery('#search-block-form\\:edit-submit').click();
    }
});
</script>
```

And here is the webflow piece:

```
<end-state id="simpleUserSearch" view="flowRedirect:user?searchString=#{simpleSearchBean.searchString}"/>

<global-transitions>
    <transition on="simpleUserSearch" to="simpleUserSearch" validate="false"/>
</global-transitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the best way to resolve this would be something like this:

```
var ajaxObject = $.ajax( {your code here} );
```

on submit do this:

```
ajaxObject.abort();
```

This would stop your running ajax script.

Comment: This would work if i would actually write the Ajax call... but i am not. It is primefaces that makes the request for me... so i can't make it variable

Comment: That is true this example would only work if you write the Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need a function for listening if the user presses `enter`... the autocomplete already does that... If you want the `search commandButton` to redirect to another page, just set the `ajax attribute to false`:

```
<p:commandButton ajax='false' action="simpleUserSearch" title="#{msgs_common['common.search']}" name="op" id="edit-submit" image="ui-icon ui-icon-search" style="float:left;"/>
```

Comment: Ah but you do need the enter, because when the autocomplete finishes it's list of values the enter only works on the LOV select. And not on the field anymore which i still need. And the trouble is setting the Ajax attribute to false doesn't work because the Get request still gets aborted by the finish the list request... thats why i need to stop the finish request in its track.

Comment: @RafaelCelerier Aborting an ajax request it's not a good practice... you have to improve your logic, you have to find alternative,good ways... I still don't understand what/why doesn't work for you; try http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompleteSelect.jsf - I see there that the ajax works and also if you press enter it shows you the dialog requested.

Comment: The ajax doesn't work... in the pojo field type in Lala and press enter and the popup does show but isn't filled in. They also force selection wich means if the LOV shows up you can only choose between those and press enter, wich i don't want... i still want the inputfield value to be able to get searched on too. And the only good way that i can actually think about is, throw away primefaces and make the autocomplete with JQuery and a javacontroller... but allas that isn't going to happen anytime soon.

Comment: This is the Primefaces Autocomplete.java. Another way would be to add to returned list, the autocomplete String value

Comment: Ok that might work, but it still doesn't fix the pressing enter during fill list requests... wich is my biggest concern